i have a problem in login functionality using tokens and useContext in react.js, it gives me unautorized 401. do i have a problem here?
i want to use useContext and tokens for login functionality for the react website, i want to     make sure that in these files the code is correct, it is giving me 401 unauthorized or where the  issue might be
i have APIs made using asp.net 8 MVC and i have MySQL db connected to it
AuthContext:
    import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';

    const AuthContext = createContext();

    const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [token, setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem('token') || '');

    const login = async (email, password) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get("/src/assets/Constants.json");
            const apiBaseUrl = response.data.API_HOST;
            const loginResponse = await axios.post(`${apiBaseUrl}/api/api is here`, { email, password });
            const { token } = loginResponse.data;
            setUser({ email }); // Set the user object with the email
            setToken(token);
            localStorage.setItem('token', token);
            return { success: true };
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Login failed', error);
            return { success: false, message: 'Login failed. Please check your credentials and try again.' };
        }
    };

    const logout = () => {
        setUser(null);
        setToken('');
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, token, login, logout }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
    };
     export { AuthContext, AuthProvider };

LOGINPAGE:

    import { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";
    import { AuthContext } from '../../context/AuthContext';

    const LoginPopup = ({ setShowLogin }) => {
    const { user, login, logout, setLoggedInUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [currState, setCurrState] = useState("Sign Up");
    const [showAddressForm, setShowAddressForm] = useState(false);
    const [customerId, setCustomerId] = useState(null);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };


    const handleLoginSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const response = await axios.get("/src/assets/Constants.json");
            const apiBaseUrl = response.data.API_HOST;

            const customersResponse = await axios.get(`${apiBaseUrl}/api/Customer/login`);
            const customers = customersResponse.data;

            const matchedCustomer = customers.find(customer =>
                customer.email === formData.email && customer.password === formData.password
            );

            if (matchedCustomer) {
                const { token } = customersResponse.data;
                setLoggedInUser(matchedCustomer);
                setSnackbarMessage('Login Successful!');
                setSnackbarSeverity('success');
                setSnackbarOpen(true);
                console.log('Snackbar set to open (success): ', true);
            } else {
                setSnackbarMessage("Login failed. Please check your credentials and try again.");
                setSnackbarSeverity("error");
                setSnackbarOpen(true);
                console.log('Snackbar set to open (error): ', true);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error during login:", error);
            setSnackbarMessage("Login failed. Please check your credentials and try again.");
            setSnackbarSeverity("error");
            setSnackbarOpen(true);
            console.log('Snackbar set to open (error): ', true);
        }
    };

    


    return (
    // return stuff
    )
        
    };

    export default LoginPopup;`

